# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([test-topic,0])

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I try to use Confluent platform and make high-level Kafka requests to the REST end-point using [this code](https://github.com/seanpquig/confluent-platform-spark-streaming) as an example.

I use the following Kafka parameters:

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "schema.registry.url" -> "http://localhost:8081",
  "group.id" -> "EventConsumer",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest"
)
```

This is the error I get when I try to run the code. The error occurs at the line:

```
@transient val kafkaStream: DStream[(String, Object)] =
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Object, StringDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder](
    ssc, kafkaParams, Set(topic)
  )
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for
>   Set([test-topic,0])   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
>     at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98)  at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
>     at
>   kafka.EventsConsumer$.delayedEndpoint$kafka$EventsConsumer$1(EventsConsumer.scala:53)
>     at
>   kafka.EventsConsumer$delayedInit$body.apply(EventsConsumer.scala:22)
>     at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)   at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)   at
>   kafka.EventsConsumer$.main(EventsConsumer.scala:22)   at
>   kafka.EventsConsumer.main(EventsConsumer.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

UPDATE:

I tried to change `localhost` to IP, but still get the same problem.

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the leader is not available for the topic partition. Try describing the topic and check if there is any leader available for the partition 0 of test-topic. This happens if all the replicas of the partition are down. If  you have replication factor of 1 then this is the most likely reason.

Comment: I try to get the content of the Kafka topic using `curl -i -X GET "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v1+json" http://localhost:8082/topics/test-topic` and received the response `{"name":"test-topic","configs":{},"partitions":[{"partition":0,"leader":0,"replicas":[{"broker":0,"leader":true,"in_sync":true}]}]}`. So, I assume that there is no problem with the partition. How to check more details?